# Pl/pgSQL anonymous code block fails on [42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, anonymous-function

Assuming the simplified `DO` anonymous code block below in a `sql` script which I import on application start:

```
-- table definitions omitted
-- assume I want to use anonymous code because of looping

DO
$$
DECLARE
    parentId BIGINT;
    inputArray VARCHAR[][] := ARRAY [['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B'], ['c', 'C']];
    input VARCHAR[];
BEGIN
    FOREACH input SLICE 1 IN ARRAY inputArray
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO myParent (name) VALUES (input[1]) RETURNING id AS parentId;
        INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) VALUES (parentId, input[2]);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Upon import and executing the script, it fails on the following error:

> ```
> [42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data 
> Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 13 at SQL statement
> ```

I read the PostgreSQL `DO` statement documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html and it says:

> DO executes an anonymous code block, or in other words a transient anonymous function in a procedural language.
>
> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void. It is parsed and executed a single time.

I would expect the `INSERT` statements within the `DO` anonymous code to execute with no hassle and go on. As said, it is a function with no parameters and returning void. Why it is expected result data and something to store them into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that the `RETURNING` causes the problem and confuses the return type of the entire block. The `AS` should be replaced with `INTO` and then the block starts to work flawlessly.

- Erroneous:

  ```
  INSERT INTO myParent (name) VALUES (input[1]) RETURNING id AS parentId;
  ```
- Correct:

  ```
  INSERT INTO myParent (name) VALUES (input[1]) RETURNING id INTO parentId;
  ```